# For Each Infinite Loop

Tags: java, foreach, linked-list

I'm a beginner programmer and I  have created a method that takes user input in a string, checks whether it is an integer or a character, converts it and then passes it onto the next part of the method which is a for each loop which checks the id values of instances of the Person object stored in a linked list.

However it is creating an infinite loop and I do not know how to break it so that it only outputs once. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I've only included what I beleive to be the problem method, if you need more parts of the program please let me know and I will add it.

```
public void theSiv() {
        System.out.println("Please enter client Id:");
        String s = In.nextLine();
        boolean isValidInteger = false;
        char choice = 'p';
        boolean exists = false;
        int searchid = 0;
        try
        {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            isValidInteger = true;
            searchid = i;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            choice = s.charAt(0);
        }

        while (choice !='x'){
            for (Person b:clients)
                if  (b.getId() == searchid){
                    exists = true;
                    System.out.println("found client");}

            if(exists == false)
                System.out.println("  No such client");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Btw, you should use `{` and `}` to  identify better your scopes. For instance, your `found client` will always be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite loop is your `while (choice !='x'){`, because nothing modifies `choice` in the body of your `while` loop. If I understand your code, then you could change to an `if` like

```
if (choice != 'x') {
```